# sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'SalesProduct.SaleId' in 'field list'" Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize-js, back-end, orm

Estou fazendo um projeto no qual preciso realizar associações entre tabelas utilizando ORM (sequelize). No erro me mostra que ele não consegue encontrar a coluna **SaleId** dentro da tabela **SalesProduct**, e realmente não vai, pois em nenhum momento criei uma coluna chamada **SaleId**, o nome da coluna é **sale_id**.

Fiz a busca pelo search/lupa no vscode e o único lugar onde existe a nomenclatura **SaleId** são nos testes do projeto.

**MIGRATIONS**

```
migrations/20220103205014-create-sales.js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('sales', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'users',
          key: 'id',
        }
      },
      seller_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      total_price: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
      },
      delivery_address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      delivery_number: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      sale_date: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      status: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, _Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('sales');
  }
};
```

```
20220103205516-create-sales-product.js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('sales_products', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      sale_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'sales',
          key: 'id',
        }
      },
      product_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'products',
          key: 'id',
        }
      },
      quantity: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, _Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('sales_products');
  }
};
```

**MODELS**

```
models/sales.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const sales = sequelize.define('Sale', {
    user_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, foreignKey: true },
    seller_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, foreignKey: true },
    total_price: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    delivery_address: DataTypes.STRING,
    delivery_number: DataTypes.STRING,
    sale_date: DataTypes.DATE,
    status: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'sales',
  });
  sales.associate = (models) => {
    models.Sale.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      as: 'users',
    });
    models.Sale.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'seller_id',
      otherKey: 'user_id',
    })
  }
  return sales;
};
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 const SalesProduct = sequelize.define('SalesProduct', {
   sale_id: {
     type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     primaryKey: true,
     foreignKey: true
   },
   product_id: {
     type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     primaryKey: true,
     foreignKey: true
   },
    quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'sales_products',
  });
  SalesProduct.associate = (models) => {
    models.SalesProduct.belongsToMany(models.Sale, {
      foreignKey: 'sale_id',
      as: 'sales',
      through: SalesProduct,
    });
    models.SalesProduct.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
      foreignKey: 'product_id',
      as: 'products',
      through: SalesProduct,
    });
  }
  return SalesProduct;
};
```

**SERVICES**

```
services/ProductsSale.js
const { Sale, Product, SalesProduct} = require('../models');

const findAll = async () => {
  const result = await SalesProduct.findAll({
    include: [
      { model: Sale, as: 'sales' },
      { model: Product, as: 'products', through: { attributes: [] } },
    ],
  });

  return result;
};

module.exports = {
  findAll,
}
```

**CONTROLLERS**

```
controllers/details.js
const productsService = require('../services/productsSale');

const getProducts = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const result = await productsService.findAll({ where: { sale_id: id } });
  res.status(200).json(result);
}



module.exports = {
  getProducts,
}
```

Comment: E qual a sua dúvida exatamente?

Comment: Resolvi o problema utilizando "underscored: true" e o erro parou. Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas acho que por padrão o sequelize transforma em camelCase e caso esteja utilizando o underscore precisa colocar como terceiro parâmetro no método define.